# Why always calling mousePressEvent before mouseDoubleClickEvent

Tags: c++, qt, events, double-click, mousepress

please consider the following code:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        std::cout << "mousePressEvent" < std::endl;
    }

    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        std::cout << "mouseDoubleClickEvent" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Every time I process double click, the output is:

```
mousePressEvent
mouseDoubleClickEvent
```

This means Qt always call mousePressEvent as soon as one press proceed without waiting the second press. Is there a way to turn off this option, so that no mousePressEvent call will perform in case of double-click.

Comment: How can Qt predict whether you will always click second time too? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have some kind of counter, and in case of double click I must increment it by 2, in case of one click increment by one. In this case I found a workaround and I am incrementing it once each time.

Comment: As I mentioned it one comment before, I did it as you mentioned. I em just trying to avoid the call of mousePress. Whay if mu program is performing one login in case of one click and the opposite login in chase of double click. In that case both functions are called..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bypass the handling of single click event (using a `QTimer`) by the period of time equal to the `QApplication::doubleClickInterval()` value. If double click is not happened during that time, I should handle "single click", otherwise the double click should be processed.

Answer (score 0):

As it says [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent): default implementation of `mouseDoubleClickEvent` generates a normal mouse press event.

In `qwidget.cpp` you can also find comment

> mouseDoubleClickEvent() is called when the user double-clicks in the widget. If the user double-clicks, the widget receives a mouse press event, a mouse release event, (a mouse click event,) a second mouse press, this event and finally a second mouse release event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to increment by one in each event function? In case of a double click, the counter would increment two times by one.

**A more generalized solution:** eliminate the changes made by `mousePressEvent` by subtracting the value it adds (can also be negative).

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    counter += singleClickStep;
}

void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    counter -= singleClickStep;
    counter += doubleClickStep;
}
```

`singleClickStep` and `doubleClickStep` are the values by which you increment counter in each case.

Vahancho's answer solves the cases where you can't undo what was done by the single click, but the `QApplication::doubleClickInterval()` might be too long. On the other hand, with my solution, you'll already see the value between the first and the second click on your widget.

Comment: why not counter += singleClickStep(); in both cases?

Comment: @Eduard Rostomyan this is (also) for the case you mentioned, where you increment/decrement, so `singleClickStep` returns 1 and `doubleClickStep` returns -1.